# Obtain prediction score

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I'm following this [notebook](https://github.com/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/blob/master/LayoutLMv2/FUNSD/True_inference_with_LayoutLMv2ForTokenClassification_%2B_Gradio_demo.ipynb) for inference with LayoutLM. I would like to modify the code to access the prediction score, in % format for each prediction. The same way I access true_predictions and true_boxes.

So far, I tried with         `probabilities = torch.nn.functional.softmax(true_predictions, dim=-1)` like this:

```
#Until here, just following the notebook
logits = outputs.logits

predictions = logits.argmax(-1).squeeze().tolist()
token_boxes = encoding.bbox.squeeze().tolist()
probabilities = torch.nn.functional.softmax(logits, dim=-1).squeeze().tolist()

if (len(token_boxes) == 512):
    predictions = [predictions]
    token_boxes = [token_boxes]
    probabilities = [probabilities]

predictions = list(itertools.chain(*predictions))
token_boxes = list(itertools.chain(*token_boxes))
probabilities = list(itertools.chain(*probabilities))
      
is_subword = np.array(offset_mapping.squeeze().tolist())[:,0] != 0
true_predictions = [self.id2label[pred] for idx, pred in enumerate(predictions) if not is_subword[idx]]
true_boxes = [box for idx, box in enumerate(token_boxes) if not is_subword[idx]]
true_probabilities = [probability for idx, probability in enumerate(probabilities) if not is_subword[idx]]
  
for prediction, box, probability in zip(true_predictions, true_boxes, true_probabilities):
    print(probability )
```

**Output:**
[0.00010619303793646395, 3.339954128023237e-05, 2.2820451704319566e-05, 2.2919863113202155e-05, 0.0005767009570263326, 5.0725124310702085e-05, 3.0033241273486055e-05, 0.006056534126400948, 4.6057226427365094e-05, 1.2512471585068852e-05, 0.0002005402639042586, 2.0308254534029402e-05, 0.992790937423706, 3.023005228897091e-05]

Which means that there are 14 labels, with the most likely one being label #13 with 0.992 (99,2%). But that is not quite what I was aming for. I'm not looking for the probability of each label for that prediction. I'm looking for the prediction score itself. Something like this prediction has a confidence of 75%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probabilities are in range [0, 1], So, if you need percentages, Scale the output of the SoftMax activation by 100.

```py
softmax_output = [
0.00010619303793646395, 3.339954128023237e-05,
2.2820451704319566e-05, 2.2919863113202155e-05, 0.0005767009570263326,
5.0725124310702085e-05, 3.0033241273486055e-05, 0.006056534126400948,
4.6057226427365094e-05, 1.2512471585068852e-05, 0.0002005402639042586,
2.0308254534029402e-05, 0.992790937423706, 3.023005228897091e-05
]

probabilities_percentage = [round(prob * 100, 2) for prob in softmax_output]

print(probabilities_percentage)

# [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.06, 0.01, 0.0, 0.61, 0.0, 0.0, 0.02, 0.0, 99.28, 0.0]
```

EDIT 1:

Inc case you need a confdidence score for the predictions, you should look at the accuracy on unseen data (test set). If you get an accuracy of 90% in test, you could (roughly) assume that your model will hit the target 90% of the times.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself properly. From that output I can extract that there are 14 possible labels for the prediction. And the most likely one, is number 13, with 99.28%. But what I'm looking for is the prediction confidence itself, not the probability of each label. Editing the question explaining it better. Sorry again

Comment: Well in that case, it is the test set which tells you how confident can you be about predictions. If you get an accuracy of 90% in test, you could (roughly) assume that your model will hit the target 90% of the times. I will update the response :)

Comment: Isn't any way to obtain individual confidence scores (something like [this](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/i-have-trained-my-classifier-now-how-do-i-do-predictions/3625/2), but for token classification problems with transformers like LayoutLM)?

Comment: what do you exactly mean? Can you explain what do you mean by confidence/individual confidence scores?

Comment: Imagine one of my labels is "Client_Number". From my input, my model is predicting two tokens to be "Client_Number". I should have only one "Client_Number".  So I would like to pick only the one with the biggest prediction confidence score.

Comment: Would be good practice to select the correct "Client_Number" as the one with the bigger maximum value from softmax_output? Or I have a better option?

Comment: Okey. Then, the best option is to select the bigger value from the softmax output. In your multiclass problem you may want to compute the cross-entropy. It is not the "confidence" but gives you some insight about the complexity you face off. I share you a good blog about it: https://towardsdatascience.com/cross-entropy-for-classification-d98e7f974451. Overall, it quantifies the difference between the predicted probability distribution and the actual distribution of the target variable, so that entropy higher than 0 means the model did not hit, so the "confidence"/"quality" is low

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use it with new data. But may help you to understand in which cases the classification is good enough or poor.